# How to monitor NFS activity on a Linux server

Tags: linux

I've got a Linux server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4) that is running nfsd. Is there a way to find out which file(s) are currently in use on the server?

Occasionally the server CPU usage spikes to over 100% and the only thing using a nontrivial amount of CPU time is nfsd. I'm curious to find out what is causing that activity.

Comment: I posted a similar question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/38756/analyzing-linux-nfs-server-performance but never really got a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get an *idea* of what files were being accessed using an indirect method:

```
tcpdump -s 192 port nfs
```

Among a serious amount of chaff, there are "lookup" packets that contain the filename that is being opened. This doesn't include the full pathname so it's still a bit of a guessing game, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

man lsof

E.g., if the nfsd has the pid 2645, then do:

```
lsof -p 2645
```

Comment: nsfd seems to do something different from normal file access. First, there are several instances of nfsd. Second, lsof only shows three open files, two `/` (root directory) and one `/proc/2833/exe` (the process binary). No other files are shown.

Comment: lsof may work for a user mode NFS server like unfsd, but it may not work for the kernel nfs server.